# Change in date-time in mysql query does not reflect in output during report generation in Jasper studio

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I have an mysql query for jasper studio report. I have a seperate date-time calendar table added to ii. What I want to achieve is that any change in dates/month/year should reflect in the output of report table also. query as below:

```
select type, concat(DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%d-%m-%Y'),' ', TIME_FORMAT(date_time, '%H:%i:%s'))as date_time, 
count(type) as Number,  
cast( ((count(type)/total.tot)*100) as decimal(5,2)) as Percentage from AUTHENT,  (select count(type) as tot from AUTHEN) total    
WHERE  $X{[GREATER, date_time, datefrom}  AND  $X{LESS], date_time, dateto} group by type ,total.tot,date_time
```

**EDIT:** field and parameters, (moved comment to question)

```
<field name="type" class="java.lang.String"> <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription> </field> 
<field name="date_time" class="java.lang.String"/> 
<field name="Number" class="java.lang.Long"/> 
<field name="Percentage" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/> 
<parameter name="runDate" class="java.util.Date"> <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Date()]]></defaultValueExpression> </parameter> 
<parameter name="datefrom" class="java.util.Date"/> 
<parameter name="dateto" class="java.util.Date">
```

I am not getting the output of records according to dates we input in 
`datefrom` and `dateto` during report generation. want to know what is wrong ??

Comment: <field name="type" class="java.lang.String">
   <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
  </field>
  <field name="date_time" class="java.lang.String"/>
  <field name="Number" class="java.lang.Long"/>
  <field name="Percentage" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
 </subDataset>
 <parameter name="runDate" class="java.util.Date">
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Date()]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="datefrom" class="java.util.Date"/>
 <parameter name="dateto" class="java.util.Date">

Comment: Next time edit the question (link under question), instead of passing as comment (I have already moved it question).

Comment: you need to ask a new question, you can't edit current question change it to another. (its also better to ask new, so people can see it). I have rollback to prevision revision.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a `java.sql.Timestamp` (date and time) with `java.util.Date` (only date), that is not really wrong but certainly passing same date in `datefrom` and `dateto`, will not give any result (in can't be both `>` and  `<`), and it will hardly equals.

Maybe you should consider comparing only on Date

```
WHERE  DATE(date_time)>=DATE($P{datefrom}) AND DATE(date_time)<=DATE($P{dateto})
```

Comment: Try to edit question, make clear exactly what is not working, your query, the relevant jrxml, the parameter values ecc.  Do you manage to get any records? [mcve]

Comment: @vanj, have you ever seen records in your table??, include the complete jrxml file.

Comment: Probably yes, but I need all information (post jrxml in link)

Comment: Its resolved. I had not added parameters in dataset for table. Now I have added I am getting the table too.

Comment: Thank you Petter for the WHERE condition.